# Understanding Python __init__

Tags: python, python-2.7, parameters, initialization, init

I have a class called Game in which I have

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
```

and below everything I have

```
def main():
    g = Game()
    while True:
        g.__init__(5,10,4)
```

when running my program I get the following error:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 4 arguments (1 given)
```

I suppose my understanding of `__init__` must be lacking, but I don't understand why this happens. Can init not take parameters?

Comment: You should almost never explicitely be calling `init`. It is called *implicitely* when you do `Game()`. Note, the error is coming from that line, because it is only passing a single argument (`self`) to `__init__` but it also requires `x`, `y`, and `z`

Comment: excepted sometimes when doing `super().__init__()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't call **__init__** explicitly from the main program; this is called automatically when you create an instance (object) of type **Game**.  What you need is much simpler:

```
def main():
    g = Game(5, 10, 4)
```

The four arguments are **self** and the three integers; the error comes from the original formation, where you gave it only **self**.

Also, note that your last two lines would have been an infinite loop to initialize the object.  This would make your game very boring, as it would never finish initializing.  :-)